# File contains no section headers on Centos

Tags: centos

When I tried to install CMake but writing the following

```
sudo yum install cmake
```

I got the following error

```
File contains no section headers.
file: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/mcepl-vim8-epel-7.repo, line: 2
'<!doctype html>\n
```

Please help me to fix this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by deleting file:///etc/yum.repos.d/mcepl-vim8-epel-7.repo